# Slack OAuth asking for domain twice?

Tags: oauth, slack-api

I've got a mobile app that needs to authenticate against Slack.

When I launch a browser to https://slack.com/oauth/authorize (as per [API](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) docs), it first asks for the user's domain. When that is entered, it takes you to a login screen which again asks for the user's domain.

Once the user enters the domain again, and their credentials, everything is working fine, but the process is a little clunky.

I've tested a few other web and mobile apps and they seem to show the same behaviour. Is there a workaround for this that anyone has found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out that it was a Slack bug and they've fixed it now.